# How to use multiple SES account within one AWS id

Tags: javascript, email, nodemailer, amazon-ses

I am using AWS SES with nodemailer for sending email. I have 3 different environment( Prod, Stage, Develpment ), all of them is running on one SES service. The problem is, as stage and development is used for testing purpose , so we use fake email Ids to test. When we send email to these fake IDs , it gets bounced and increases our bounce rate. Since we have only one SES service and if bounce rate goes to 10% they will pause email service on Prod too.

My question is, is there any way we can use AWS SES separately for each of the environment under one AWS account only.

Answer (score 0):

For development purposes you can use [MailCatcher](https://mailcatcher.me/)

This is SMTP server which catches any message sent to it to display in a web interface. Any fake email addresses will be acceptable.